# Close PreferenceActivity when Pressing Power button ,Open Same PreferenceActivity again,If I click on app icon in Andorid

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

Clicking on Power button is destroying "PreferenceActivity" ,But If I lock emulator I don't want to
Destroy PreferenceActivity,instead of this I want to Close ,and when I click on app again I want to display PreferenceActivity in Android,Could anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure? My PreferenceActivity is still in foreground If I press the power button.

Comment: I think it is destroyed..